# COM / OLE / ActiveX / IDispatch confusion

Tags: com, activex, ole, idispatch

I can't wrap my head around the differences among these terms.

Are COM and ActiveX synonyms?

Is ActiveX object just a COM object that exposes IDispatch?

Lots of older MSDN pages mention IDispatch without any COM context. Does it have a separate history, and was just introduced under the COM 'umbrella' later in its lifecycle?

Where does OLE fit in? Is its (considerable) presence in MFC naming and MSDN in general - all just legacy?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) gives some insight, but not much. I couldn't find a more in depth reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found some quotes from [COM Programming by Example](http://books.google.com/books?id=5otUpy4cLAIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22com+programming+by+example%22#PPP1,M1):

> Another thing you'll quickly find with
>   COM is that marketing had a field trip
>   day with the terminology. Rather then
>   helping to promote understanding,
>   you'll find in most cases it promotes
>   mystery. ... OLE, ActiveX, Remotable
>   Objects - which one means what this
>   week? ...
>
> COM evolved out of the solution to a
>   specific problem - how to allow a word
>   processor to edit the spreadsheet in a
>   letter without the user having to exit
>   the word processor to do it. This
>   solution was called OLE.  ... However,
>   with the second release of OLE (OLE2),
>   its creators modified OLE32.DLL to
>   expose more of the basic functionality
>   of OLE so that its API could be used
>   to allow any application to acess the
>   functionality of another. This API,
>   which hasn't changed much since 1993,
>   is what is considered to be the COM
>   API. 
>   ...
>
> Once the COM API was exposed,
>   Microsoft used it to create what were
>   then called OLE controls to allow
>   sophisticated controls (e.g., buttons
>   that spiral, list boxes that play
>   music) written in Visual C++ to be
>   accessible to Visual Basic
>   applications. Eventually this same
>   technology was used to allow a control
>   to be downloaded and used by your web
>   browser. At this point, the name
>   changed to ActiveX controls or just
>   plain ActiveX purely for marketing
>   reasons. Although you can package any
>   functionality in an ActiveX Control,
>   its requrirements have been
>   specialized for supporting a user
>   interface control.

I'm still curious about the very last sentence - must a COM object satisfy some additional requirements to qualify as an ActiveX control? - but its enough to let it go.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: "must a COM object satisfy some additional requirements to qualify as an ActiveX control" Yes. I'm not sure what they are, though. It's probably just that it has to implement some particular interface.

Comment: There is no rigid specification of this. Even the docs say that containers should gracefuly degrade when an ActiveX control does not implement an interface.

Comment: The original spec for ActiveX Controls had the interfaces needed to make a control useful in Internet Explorer and/or Visual Basic. But those sets of interfaces changed over time, and applications got more tolerant of missing interfaces, so eventually anything that supported the COM IUnknown interface could be considered an ActiveX component.

Answer (score 6):

ActiveX is marketing-ese for COM, although ActiveX is usually used in the context of "ActiveX controls" which are GUI objects.

IDispatch is an interface implemented by COM objects so that client programs can call its methods dynamically at run-time (late-binding), as opposed to at compile time where all the methods and argument types need to be known ahead of time.

OLE is the earlier version of COM.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding OLE: COM has its roots in OLE. But today, OLE may be considered to be built on top of COM and is mostly used for what its name suggests -- document linking and embedding. While COM itself defines only a couple of interfaces itself (IUnknown, IClassFactory, IMalloc etc), OLE adds a whole bunch of additional interfaces like IMoniker, IOleItemComtainer, etc.

To sum up: COM is the foundation, ActiveX and OLE are layers on top of COM.

Comment: I am currently working on a similar topic and during this I found two links which may be useful here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751972(v=vs.85).aspx#ActiveX_Controls
 '...In other words, a control, at the very least, is some COM object that supports the IUnknown interface and is also self-registering'   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159621/en-us